AuditD - tuning out parent and children
I'm reading over the AuditD readmes and I see how you can use filters but is there a way that you can tune out a parent and any activity they create along with their children processes?
For example, I have /usr/bin/python3 /var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.Azure.Monitor.AzureMonitorLinuxAgent-1.28.11/agent.py and it creates a lot of noisy by doing the same activity constantly.
